# Pandas - Incremental Count that does not increase with consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I'm trying to do an incremental count on my dataframe, but I need certain conditions to apply.

**Original DF:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[[123,'1/1','Yes'],
[123,'1/1','Yes'],
[123,'1/1','No'],
[123,'1/1','No'],
[123,'1/1','No'],
[123,'1/1','Yes'],
[123,'1/2','Yes'],
[123,'1/1','No'],
[123,'1/2','No'],
[123,'1/2','Yes'],
[123,'1/2','No'],
[123,'1/2','Yes']
], columns=['AcctId','Date','Yes_No'])

df
AcctId  Date  Yes_No  
123     1/1   Yes
123     1/1   Yes
123     1/1   No
123     1/1   No
123     1/1   No
123     1/1   Yes
123     1/2   Yes
123     1/2   No
123     1/2   No
123     1/2   Yes
123     1/2   No
123     1/2   Yes
```

**Conditions:**

If `Yes_No == 'No'` then `Counter = 0`

If `Yes_No == 'Yes'` then `Counter = 1`

If `Yes_No == 'Yes'` AND previous `Yes_No == 'Yes'` then do not increase `Counter`

If `Yes_No == 'Yes'` AND previous `Yes_No == 'No'` then increase `Counter` by 1

If `Date` changes then reset `Counter`

The closest I've gotten is the following, but it wasn't able to factor in the `Date` or where `Yes_No == 'No'`:

```
df['Counter'] = (df['Yes_No'] != df['Yes_No'].shift(1)).astype(int).cumsum()
```

**Preferred Output:**

```
df
AcctId  Date  Yes_No  Counter
123     1/1   Yes     1  #Set Counter = 1 since this is first instance where 'Yes_No' == 'Yes' on 1/1
123     1/1   Yes     1  #Keep Counter = 1 since previous row 'Yes_No' == 'Yes'
123     1/1   No      0  #Set Counter = 0 since 'Yes_No' == 'No'
123     1/1   No      0  #Keep Counter = 0 since 'Yes_No' == 'No'
123     1/1   No      0  #Keep Counter = 0 since 'Yes_No' == 'No'
123     1/1   Yes     2  #Increase counter to 2 since this is 2nd non-consecutive instance of 'Yes' on 1/1
123     1/2   Yes     1  #Reset Counter to 1 since 'Date' changed
123     1/2   No      0
123     1/2   No      0
123     1/2   Yes     2  #Increase Counter to 2 since this is 2nd non-consecutive instance of 'Yes' on 1/2
123     1/2   No      0
123     1/2   Yes     3  #Increase Counter to 3 since this is 3rd non-consecutive instance of 'Yes' on 1/2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to do this with columns you'd need to compute two more columns to figure out date changes.

Otherwise my first thought is just to use a `for` loop, would make this a breeze.